# echo outputting "ECHO is off" in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cpu-usage

I am using a simple script that gets the CPU usage of the current system. 
However It just prints "`ECHO is off`"

Here is my script.

```
set temp=
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do (set temp=%%p)

echo %temp%
```

Comment: Echo will print that if you give it no arguments. Which means temp is empty.

Comment: i set temp to p. and p is definitely not empty,

Comment: Then test it with `set temp`, it will say something like `the variable "test" is undefined`

Comment: `wmic cpu get loadpercentage` will output three lines - "Load Percentage" - the load percentage value - and a blank line. You're skipping the first line, but on the last iteration of the for loop, temp is being set to the blank line (null).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TEMP` is a logical, but a very bad name for a a variable. By default, it is a pointer to a temporary directory and changing it can produce unexpected results. (`TMP` points to the same place, for historical reasons...)

IF the variable is empty, which it is, you will get the `ECHO` state reported. The syntax `ECHO(%whatever%` will report the contents of `whatever`, even if it is empty.

`WMIC` output is UNICODE, confusing `FOR/f`. which see the bytes following `00 0D 00` as a new (empty) line.

```
set var=
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do IF NOT DEFINED var set var=%%p

ECHO(var=%var%
```

should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Output from wmic has multiple lines, and the last of them are empty. Your `for` loop is reading all of them and setting the variable to the content of theese lines, so when the loop ends, you variable is empty and you get no data to show. Filter the output of wmic, so only lines with data will be processed. AND %temp% is a variable that holds the path to the temporary files directory. Using it as storage will give you problems.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage /value ^| find "=" ') do (set "%%p")
echo LoadPercentage: %LoadPercentage%
```